# Custom Web Part Connecting to Filter Web Part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I have built a custom web part using Visual Studio. Is it possible to use a SharePoint built-in Filter Web Part on top of my web part to filter the results?

Any thought or code sample would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoints built in filter web parts are known as **Filter Providers**.

To allow you to connect those to your web part you need to make it a **Filter Consumer** by implementing an interface.

See [MSDN - Writing a Simple Filter Consumer Web Part Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms569191%28v=office.12%29.aspx)